# How can i draw a general resource graph which cannot be completely reduced but which is free from deadlock?

Tags: operating-systems

How can i draw a general resource graph which cannot be completely reduced but which is free from deadlock?

A general resource graph which can be completely reduced and hence is free from deadlock is shown below.

[image]

As depicted above, R1 and R2 are resources and P1 and P2 are processes.

Comment: I see now that you already asked a similar question here, had it closed, and then asked a cleaned-up version on CSE. I suspect that the question is fine now, but for future reference, if you edit your original question, it can be reopened. Closure is considered a temporary measure to give you the opportunity to improve the question before answers start streaming in. (Once they come, it takes away a lot of your flexibility to improve the question)

Comment: [As was asked the last time you posted this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83999/how-do-i-reduce-the-following-general-resource-graph#comment180110_83999), what have you tried so far?  What are your thoughts?  What prevents you from answering this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

A general resource graph which cannot be completely reduced but which is free from deadlock is illustrated below.

R1 and R2 are reusable resources, and P1 and P2 processes.

[image]